# Crawling wikipedia

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm going through crawling wikipedia using website downloader for windows, i was looking through the whole options in this tool to find an option to download wikipedia pages for specific period, for example from 2005 untill now.

Does anyone get any idea about crawling the website in specific period of time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a try to the [Wikipedia API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) and your programming skills.

Comment: well, you can grab almost any data from wiki with it, also partial, prev. revisions, etc. Try to read it's manual.

Comment: is it possible to extract the meaning of the word in different language using Wikipedia API !!!
do you think it's possible ?

Comment: Didn't try, but there is the property `langlinks (ll)` to get the list of all interlanguage links from the given page and you can get the content for the specific language to switch to the corresponding subdomain in API's URL then.

Comment: yup .... I successfully get the result that i want using the wikipeda API ... but wondering, have you ever dealt with the wikipedia dumpdata before !!!

Comment: No. Actually I almost had no project which works with wiki more than to grab some short (one paragraph) definition for some subject (usually for some location). I don't really see any reason to use it in other ways and to display full information from wiki (if I need so I just put some link to the corresponding Wiki's article) if only you are not trying to write some wiki's wrapper.

Answer (score 6):

Why not [download the SQL database containing all of Wikipedia](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/)?

You can then [query it using SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Doing_SQL_queries_on_the_current_database_dump).

Comment: the link up there if I'm not mistaken for English, how about other languages ?

Comment: Do you need a link to Google?

Comment: They don't seem to offer dumps older than 2009. The DVD they sell appears to be from circa 2007.

Comment: actually, while i'm looking to the dumps data, if i download all of it it will occupied a huge space in my HD, i would like to download some of the data, specifically i would like to download the dumps for some languages only, not the whole dumps data which contains more than 250 language !

Answer (score 2):

There should be no need to do web scraping; use the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuick_start_guide) to directly request the information you want. I'm not sure what you mean by "wikipedia pages for a specific period" - do you mean last edited at a certain time? If so, while skimming, I noticed an API call that lets you get a look at the last `n` revisions; just ask for the last revision and see what its date is.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the website in question offers the archive and mostly don't so its not possible in a straightforward way to crawl a sample started from specific date. But you can implement some intelligence in your crawler to read the page created date or something like that.

But you can also look at Wikipedia API at http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php